# MySQL delete multiple rows in one statement

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I want to delete multiple rows in my MySql-Database in one Statement and i wrote a statement according to [MySQL Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html).

Here is my Statement:

```
DELETE S, P, E
FROM Person P 
JOIN Student S ON S.PersonID = P.PersonID
JOIN Employee E ON E.PersonID = P.PersonID
WHERE P.Date < '2010-01-01';
```

which throws the following error:

> Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails 
>   (`DB`.`Student`, CONSTRAINT `FK_Student_Person`  FOREIGN KEY
>   (`PersonID`) REFERENCES `Person` (`PersonID`))

what's my mistake?

Splitting this statement into 3 and deleting Employee, Student and Person in that order works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't delete record from Person table because for table Student have a foreign key of PersonID. If you still want to delete record then you can use query like this

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
DELETE S, P, E
FROM Person P 
JOIN Student S ON S.PersonID = P.PersonID
JOIN Employee E ON E.PersonID = P.PersonID
WHERE P.Date < '2010-01-01';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Comment: I think MySQL should internal delete the Student and Employees anyway first. Otherwise the reference to Person would be missing. So when you delete Student first and Person afterwards, this Error should not occur

Comment: Right #fubo.Using `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;` it will not concern any constraints. Please accept my answer if this works for you.